# Entity Framework executes both INSERT and UPDATE stored procedures when you do INSERT

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure, which is mapped in an Entity Framework 4.1 object.  The call is made within the

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
            try
            {
                DbEntity.Car.AddObject(CarInfo);
                DbEntity.SaveChanges();

/* Other object savings */

                transaction.Complete();

                DbEntity.AcceptAllChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }
            finally
            {
                DbEntity.Dispose();
            }
}
```

I see the stored procedure mapping done currently.  If I execute the stored procedure alone on MS SQL server, it executes it correctly.

Here is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Carinsert] @Qty               INT
                              ,@StyleID          INT
                              ,@TFee             MONEY
                              ,@HWayTax          MONEY
                              ,@OFees            MONEY
                              ,@OFeesDescription NTEXT
                              ,@MUp              DECIMAL(18, 4)
                              ,@BAss             MONEY
                              ,@PriceMSRP        MONEY
                              ,@PriceSpecial     MONEY
AS
BEGIN
  SET nocount ON

  DECLARE @PTotal MONEY
  DECLARE @TaxFeesNet MONEY
  DECLARE @CarID INT

  SET @TaxFeesNet = Isnull(@TFee, 0) + Isnull(@HWayTax, 0)
                    + Isnull(@OFees, 0)

  IF( @PriceSpecial IS NULL )
    BEGIN
        SET @PTotal = @PriceMSRP + @TaxFeesNet
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @PTotal = @PriceSpecial + @TaxFeesNet
    END

  INSERT INTO Car
              (Qty
               ,StyleID
               ,MUp
               ,BAss
               ,PriceMSRP
               ,PriceSpecial
               ,TFee
               ,HWayTax
               ,OFees
               ,OFeesDescription
               ,PriceTotal)
  VALUES      (@Qty
               ,@StyleID
               ,@MUp
               ,@BAss
               ,@PriceMSRP
               ,@PriceSpecial
               ,@TFee
               ,@HWayTax
               ,@OFees
               ,@OFeesDescription
               ,@PTotal)

    SELECT Scope_identity() AS CarID
END
```

If I execute this like on MS SQL it calculates the PriceTotal column in the table as 3444.00, which is correct.

```
    @Qty= 5,
    @StyleID = 331410,
    @TFee = NULL,
    @HWayTax = NULL,
    @OFees = NULL,
    @OFeesDescription = NULL,
    @MUp = 4,
    @BAss = 10000,
    @PriceMSRP = 20120,
    @PriceSpecial = 3444
```

When I run the MVC web application, and I debug & see these are the values passed and the PriceTotal comes to 20120.00

I couldn't figure out why it does not do the IF ELSE calculation & use the price.

Does anybody else see something weird?  This has been daunting for few days now.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks

**Update**
I updated the title to better guide others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few minutes of posting the question, I figured it all out.

There was actually 2 bug.

1. Entity framework used the UPDATE stored procedure even when I try to INSERT new records.  Just for records, the UPDATE stored procedure required the CarID [primary key].  May be EF first does the INSERT and then does the UPDATE right away, even for creating new records?
2. The UPDATE sproc had a bug checking for NULL using <>.  It should have been IS NOT NULL

In anycase, now This is a bigger issue.  How to force EF to use INSERT sproc and not the UPDATE when I only want to do is create a new record?

I tried
DbEntityContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(carInfo, EntityState.Added);
and still EF kept on calling the UPDATE sproc.